# Different results using cor.test() and sm_statCorr() for spearman's rho?

Tags: r, ggplot2, correlation

I'm comparing two different surveys for two different symptoms of migraine. Because I want to present the correlation for each symptom in both a table and a plot, I used cor.test() to retrieve the values for the table, and ggplot() and sm_statCorr() to create the plot. However, the two functions to calculate Spearman's rho give slightly different results. I suspect that it has to do with my data transformation, but I haven't been able to figure out wherein.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(stats, dplyr, ggplot2, smplot2) 

# Import and transform data
data <- matrix(c(1, "headache", 1, NA, 1, "aura", 0, 0, 2, "headache", 1, 1, 2, "aura", 0, 0, 
                 3, "headache", -1, -1, 3, "aura", 0, 1, 4, "headache", 1, 2, 4, "aura", -2, -2, 
                 5, "headache", 0, 1, 5, "aura", 1, 1, 6, "headache", 2, 2, 6, "aura", 0, 0, 
                 7, "headache", 0, 0, 7, "aura", 0, 0, 8, "headache", 1, 1, 8, "aura", 0, 0, 
                 9, "headache", 1, 0, 9, "aura", 0, 0, 10, "headache", 1, -1, 10, "aura", 0, 0, 
                 11, "headache", 0, 1, 11, "aura", 0, 0, 12, "headache", 0, 0, 12, "aura", 0, 0), 
               nrow = 24, ncol = 4, byrow = T)
colnames(data) = c("id", "symptom", "survey_1", "survey_2")
data <- as.matrix(data)
data <- as.data.frame(data)
data$id <- as.numeric(data$id)
data$survey_1 <- as.numeric(data$survey_1)
data$survey_2 <- as.numeric(data$survey_2)
data$symptom = factor(data$symptom, levels=c("headache", "aura"))

# Create plot with sm_statCorr
data_n <- data %>% group_by(symptom, survey_1, survey_2) %>% tally() %>% ungroup()
data_n <- data_n[,c("symptom", "survey_1", "survey_2", "n")]

ggplot(data_n, aes(x = survey_1, y = survey_2)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = n)) +
  sm_statCorr(data = data, aes(x = survey_1, y = survey_2), corr_method = "spearman") +
  facet_wrap(. ~ symptom)

# Perform cor.test
cor.test(data[(data$symptom == "headache"), ]$survey_1, 
         data[(data$symptom == "headache"), ]$survey_2,
         method = "spearman")
cor.test(data_aura <- data[(data$symptom == "aura"), ]$survey_1, 
         data_aura <- data[(data$symptom == "aura"), ]$survey_2,
         method = "spearman")
```

The cor.test() gives me Spearman's rho 0.5028556 for headache and 0.8174239 for aura.
In the plot, however, the same values are given as 0.55 and 0.83, respectively:
[image]

Comment: Hi Friede, thank you for your response. I think it's not because of the intercept, because if I analyze only one of the symptoms, in a data frame that only contains that symptom (so that I don't have to group and ungroup the data for the ggplot, and use facet_wrap(), the results are the same for sm_statCorr() and cor.test(). So it must be an error introduced by the data handling, in some way?

Comment: it does seem like your grouping / faceting creates the issue as `ggplot(data = data, aes(x=survey_1, y=survey_2)) + sm_statCorr(corr_method = "spearman") +  facet_wrap(. ~ symptom)` seems to return the expected values. I think the difference is due to the groups are created for the facets using data_n` and not `data`. So could try swapping the data that is used at the top level: Does `ggplot(data=data, aes(x = survey_1, y =survey_2)) +   geom_point(data=data_n, aes(x = survey_1, y = survey_2, size = n)) +    sm_statCorr(corr_method = "spearman") + facet_wrap(. ~ symptom)` do what you expect?

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! If you can post your suggestion as an answer, I can mark it as the correct one! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in statistics between the approaches is due to them being calculated using different data. With the plot, the statistics produced by `sm_statCorr` are grouped by the `symptom` column from the `data_n` dataframe, as opposed to using `data` for the `cor.test`.

This happens as the `facet` call looks for the `facet`ting variable in the data at the top level `ggplot` call, which in the question was `data_n`.

You can get the same groupings by swapping the data that is used at the top level:

```
ggplot(data=data, aes(x = survey_1, y =survey_2)) +   
   geom_point(data=data_n, aes(x = survey_1, y = survey_2, size = n)) +   
   sm_statCorr(corr_method = "spearman") + 
   facet_wrap(. ~ symptom) # this now uses `symptom` from data`
```